# How can I get events about a specific email in sendgrid using java?

Tags: java, spring, webhooks, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to get the event about a email in sendgrid with a specific id, use webhook to get it but it doesnt give me nothing, only tags about enable or the type of event.
I tried use webhook or `/message/{msg_id}` with method get but nothing.
Here is some code i used

```
@Override
public String getMessages(){
     try {
  SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
  Request request = new Request();
  request.setMethod(Method.GET);
  request.setEndpoint("user/webhooks/event/settings");
  Response response = sg.api(request);
  System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println(response.getBody());
  System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
} catch (IOException ex) {
  throw ex;
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public String getMessages(){
     try {
         SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(sendgridKEY);
         Request request = new Request();
         request.setMethod(Method.GET);
         request.setEndpoint("/messages/{msg_id}");
         Response response = sg.api(request);
         System.out.println(response.getBody());
         System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
        }catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

I cant get the events about a specific email yet.
What can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SendGrid Event Webhook actively POSTs data to your endpoint. You can't query it, you just need to set it up, store the received data on that side, then you can look into your local datastore as needed.

You can use Email Activity in their UI to query specific messages that happened in the recent past.